# Comparative usage of the definite article "the"

Tags: definite-article

I've heard from native speakers that the definite article "the" is needed in the first sentence below but not the second one:

1. Genetic testing predicted all **the** markings of my cat correctly.
2. Select all columns whose title includes the letter A.

I wonder why that is the case. The structure of the above two sentences seems similar. In both cases, we have a *plural* noun that is followed by a phrase that adds more information about it. (*"of my cat"* in Example 1 and *"whose title includes the letter A"* in Example 2.)

Answer (score 0):

The marking of a specific cat and so, all the marking of my cat.

Whose denotes possession.

Select all columns (in general) whose title includes the letter A. (Maybe selection of other columns is also possible.)

Select all the columns whose title includes the letter A. (Mandatory) (Maybe the selection should be of only one.)

Comment: Thank you!!! Can you please elaborate a bit more on the difference between the last two examples in your response, that is, "all columns whose" and "all the columns whose"?

Comment: I think the suggestion is that "all the columns" starting with "A" means *all and only* the "A" columns, while "all columns" means *at least* the "A" columns (and possibly others). But I'm not sure I agree. I would probably interpret both sentences the same way.

Answer (score 0):

"all the" is a short form for "all of the": see this [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80412/is-of-necessary-in-all-of) for more details.

> Genetic testing predicted all of the markings of my cat correctly.
> Select all of the columns whose title includes the letter A.

The second sentence is a more concise way of saying the same thing, and could be used for either sentence.

> Genetic testing predicted all markings of my cat correctly.
> Select all columns whose title includes the letter A.

I would prefer the "all of the" structure for both sentences.